# Alternative to using relationship with SQLite

Tags: android

I'm creating an app which is going to have some data that is stored in an SQLite database. I want the user to be able to create "folders" which can be assigned to each data item.

I was going to do this using a one to many relationship e.g. one "folder" can have many data objects under it but having looked at relationships with SQLite and Android it seems that this would only work in 2.2+ so I'm just wondering what the alternative is?

Any information is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still have relationships; older versions of SQLite just won't enforce them.  As a stopgap, you can build triggers to do it; in fact there's a [handy generator](http://www.rcs-comp.com/site/index.php/view/Utilities-SQLite_foreign_key_trigger_generator) that will generate the SQL for you to use as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising - i'll still leave this open though to see if anyone else has any ideas/alternatives - thanks a lot though.

Comment: It seems to be the best way for me is triggers, thanks for the answer.